# openshift eclipse publish stuck

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, openshift

I tried to publish my java /spring boot app to openshift cloud platform via eclipse openshift plugin and it stucks at 'Preparing build for deployment'. For to be sure I waited for all day but there were no changes.

restarting the app and cleaning it did not worked

Is there any way to solve this, or any other way to deploy my spring boot app to openshift by using ssh connection etc...

here is console output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ site ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1406 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ site ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to /var/lib/openshift/581b33a789f5cf45fd000026/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes
[WARNING] /var/lib/openshift/581b33a789f5cf45fd000026/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/org/site/models/AnasayfaDuzen.java: /var/lib/openshift/581b33a789f5cf45fd000026/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/org/site/models/AnasayfaDuzen.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /var/lib/openshift/581b33a789f5cf45fd000026/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/org/site/models/AnasayfaDuzen.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ site ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/openshift/581b33a789f5cf45fd000026/app-root/runtime/repo/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ site ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/lib/openshift/581b33a789f5cf45fd000026/app-root/runtime/repo/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ site ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ site ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [site] in   [/var/lib/openshift/581b33a789f5cf45fd000026/app-root/runtime/repo/target/site]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [10915 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/581b33a789f5cf45fd000026/app-root/runtime/repo/webapps/ROOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ site ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact webapps/ROOT.war to /var/lib/openshift/581b33a789f5cf45fd000026/app-root/runtime/repo/target/site.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 44.136s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 15 01:22:27 EST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/170M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Preparing build for deployment
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your log files for further information about the problem that you are having?

You can check your log files by using the `rhc tail` command, or by sshing into your application and looking in the ~/app-root/logs directory.

You can learn more about checking your log files in our [Developer Portal](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html)